# add virtual field to model in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my model class.

```
 namespace Details.Models
    {
        public class COMPLETE_DETAILS
        {
            [Key]
            public long COMPLETE_DETAIL_ID { get; set; }
            public string TRUCK_NO { get; set; }
            public string CHALLAN_NO { get; set; }
            public string L_R_NO { get; set; }
            public string DEALER_NAME { get; set; }
            public string SOURCE_DESTINATION { get; set; }
            public string ORIGINAL_DESTINATION { get; set; }
            public string COMPANY_DESTINATION { get; set; }
            public decimal? CEMENT_BAG_NO { get; set; }
            public decimal? RATE_PER_BAG { get; set; }
            public decimal? TOTAL_COST_PERSONAL { get; set; }
            public decimal? TOTAL_COST_COMPANY { get; set; }
            public decimal? NET_PROFIT { get; set; }
            public Nullable<DateTime> DATE { get; set; }
            public decimal? OTHER_EXPENSES { get; set; }
            **public virtual long? ROW_NO { get; set; }**
        }
    }
```

i want to add a virtual field to my model class but it`s not worked for me. In my data Base the table name is COMPLETE_DETAILS and it has all the field except ROW_NO so there is any another option to make a virtual field in model class of mvc3

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using for example Entity Framework to link for example your MS-SQL database with c# class. So, you can list all required properties in c# class and then create new class inherited from COMPLETE_DETAILS with one extra field ROW_NO and calculate it programmaticaly or whatever you wish.

```
public class COMPLETE_DETAILS_CUSTOM: COMPLETE_DETAILS
{
    public virtual long? ROW_NO { get; set; }     
}
```

Some linq code:

```
using(DbContext Db = new DbContext())    
{
    List<COMPLETE_DETAILS_CUSTOM> items = Db.COMPLETE_DETAILS_DBSET.Select((item, index)=> new COMPLETE_DETAILS_CUSTOM(){
        COMPLETE_DETAIL_ID = item.COMPLETE_DETAIL_ID,
        // same with other fields
        ROW_NO = index
    }).ToList();
}
```